# QTableWidget Drag Item not Removing when Dropping on Invalid area

Tags: c++, qt

Pretty much as the tittle says, when i drag an item from QTableWidget it adds a child to ui->table->children, and then it launches ChildAdded event to my eventFilter, the problem is that if i drop the dragged item into an area that doesn't accept dropping that child won't be removed from ui->table->children whereas releasing the dragged item within an area that has dropping enabled it will, and also launches ChildRemoved event.

Here is my init code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    m_ui->setupUi(this);

    m_ui->left_table->installEventFilter(this);
    m_ui->right_table->installEventFilter(this);

    m_ui->left_table->setColumnCount(1);
    m_ui->left_table->setRowCount(25);
    m_ui->left_table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"Source"});
    m_ui->left_table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    m_ui->left_table->setAcceptDrops(false);
    m_ui->left_table->setDragEnabled(true);

    m_ui->right_table->setColumnCount(1);
    m_ui->right_table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"Receiver"});
    m_ui->right_table->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    m_ui->right_table->setAcceptDrops(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
        m_ui->left_table->setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(i)));
    }

    qDebug() << "Left childs: " << m_ui->left_table->children().size();
}
```

and the event filter:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ChildAdded || event->type() == QEvent::ChildRemoved) {
        qDebug() << "Object: " << watched->objectName()
                 << " Event: " << event->type()
                 << "Childs: " << m_ui->left_table->children().size();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example of dropping on invalid area, this wont remove the child added before:

[image]

Example of dropping on valid area, this will remove the child and call the ChildRemoved event:

[image]

Comment: The question is very unclear and it is hard to understand what is your problem. For instance, _the problem is that if i drop the dragged item into an area that doesn't accept dropping that child won't be removed_ does not seem to be true, as I have just tested your code and here is the result from dropping into an area, which does not accept drops: `Left childs:  9
Object:  "left_table"  Event:  QEvent::Type(ChildAdded) Childs:  10
Object:  "left_table"  Event:  QEvent::Type(ChildRemoved) Childs:  9`. The ChildRemoved event is fired for sure. So, could you please clarify your question.

Comment: Well thats weird, because when i run the program it doesn't happen like that, the ChildRemoved event wont trigger if i do the same. Idk if this is a bug but my program should have the behavior that you are describing.

Comment: Then prepare a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue.